# React Hooks and Firestore -> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm trying to build simple to do list app with using firestore and react hooks.
The app works fine but it gives me error in the console when the checkbox is clicked :

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
>   cleanup function.
>       in CheckBox (at note-list.js:86)
>       in td (at note-list.js:85)
>       in tr (at note-list.js:84)

The checkbox component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import firebase from "../FirebaseData";

const CheckBox = (props) => {
  const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(props.each.isDone);

  const handleDone = () => {
    const notesDb = firebase.firestore().collection("notes");
    notesDb
      .doc(props.each.id)
      .update({
        isDone: !isDone,
      })
      .then(() => {
        setIsDone(!isDone);
      });
  };

  let isCheck = props.each.isDone ? true : false;

  return (
    <input
      style={{ marginLeft: "35%" }}
      type="checkbox"
      checked={isCheck}
      onChange={handleDone}
    />
  );
};

export default CheckBox;
```

I think the problem is coused because I'm using props to pass some of the firestore information. Is it ok in general to pass props from real time database to a component ?

I've tried to include useEffect inside the handleDone() and app crash and say something like

> "useEffect" is called in function  which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook

Then I've tried to take the **handleDone()** and transform it to **useHandleDone()** outside of the CheckBox component but I'm not sure how to obtain the id for **doc(id)** for the task I want to change in the firestore.

In case if it's totally wrong to use props for this task, what's the correct way ?

Thank you !